# Is there any way to get current nuxt.js middleware of page?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am curious if we can reach the current page's middleware from any component?

Comment: Not sure I quite get what you're trying to do. Can you give a concrete example ?

Comment: Sure @kissu, Let's say I have a logout button that takes action async and then switches itself with a login link. What I would like to check is whether this is happening on an auth middleware page or not, in order to take action. Thanks!

Comment: The `@nuxtjs/auth` provides a Vuex store module on which you can access `loggedIn` state and see if it's the case. You could either check this value inside of a component or, for a more global solution, plug the whole middleware on the Nuxt project config and kick the user to the login page once he is logged out. Rather than doing it on the page level, you do it higher but the result is the same at the end. The module also allow to have "unprotected" pages, by just setting a boolean.

Comment: I see auth module perfect to manage indeed. In my case, I have an `isLoggedIn` Amplify state to kick my user to login page. But the thing is I don't have one, I am using an auth modal popup, that's why I want to check middleware actually. I can redirect the user to the homepage but I don't want to do that for every page. Maybe I should create separate pages for login/logout.

Comment: What's the relation between the middleware and the modal ?

Comment: I want to check the middleware to decide either keeping the user on the same page that just logged out or redirecting to the homepage. If the page has a named `auth`  middleware I should redirect it, if not do nothing. The modal is a popup form with overlay bg, I am triggering it when the user clicks the logout link.

Comment: Why not having an array of those pages in the middleware ? Rather than checking the middleware to see if the user needs to be redirected, do the check in the middleware: if the page matches the ones in the middleware, redirect him, otherwise no action will be needed in the middleware.

Comment: Alright, looks like it's another good option for me, either @Ohgodwhy's suggestion to keep track of the middleware on the store or as you suggest an array of the private routes. Thank you for your time I will give it a try both. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware is executed prior to the component and is not initialized within the component in any way.

**Update:** Persisting the state of middleware in the `auth` store.

```
export const state = () => ({
  isPrivate: false,
})

export const mutations = {
  setPrivatePage(state, value) {
    state.isPrivate = value
  },
}

export const actions = {
  privatePage({ commit }) {
    commit('setPrivatePage', true)
  },

  publicPage({ commit }) {
    commit('setPrivatePage', false)
  },
}
```

Dispatch the action in the `middleware/auth` to set `isPrivate`:

```
await store.dispatch('auth/privatePage')
```

I added another middleware named `public` to set it back to `false`

```
export default async ({ store }) => {
  await store.dispatch('auth/publicPage')
}
```

And finally to trigger `public` on every route, add it to the `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  // Router
  router: {
    middleware: 'public',
  },
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for sharing so I think there is no way to reach what middleware took action via the context.

Comment: No. You would need to build something, e.g. a vuex module, that hold reference to the middleware that took action and committing to the store from the middleware so it's hydrated from the middleware prior to reaching the component.

Comment: Aha! yes, it might help me in my scenario explained above. Thank you, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it on

```
$router.matched.meta.middleware
```